# protobuf plugins cannot be applied closure warning IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, grpc-java, proto

i am learning protobuf and gRPC sample and using gradle plugin from here

- https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java

I am getting following error shown on screen shot.

[image]

Until i add dependency `implementation com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.9.0` in my dependencies i keep on getting following error.

```
Error:(25, 7) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UnusedPrivateParameter
  location: class MyClass
```

My  Dev Info as below

- Os: Window 10 [v1083, b17134.885]
- JDK: jdk1.8.0_181
- IntelliJ: #IU-183.5429.30, built on January 29, 2019

Answer (score 0):

In idea you might have to add the generated sources directories to your build path:

```
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src-generated")
        sourceDirs += file("src-generated")
        generatedSourceDirs += file("src-generated")
        generatedSourceDirs += file("src-generated")
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/examples/grpc-lib/build.gradle

The protobuf and the grpc-java generators both generate code that still requires the actual protobuf libraries (with the same protobuf version) to be present at compile and runtime.

EDIT:

After reading your question again I discovered that the warning/error results from protobuf internals changing.

`grpc-protobuf` Version 1.22.1 (latest) depends on `protobuf` 3.7.1.

At least between `protobuf` 3.7.1 and 3.8.0 there is some (internal?) API incompatibility. E.g. you cannot use protobuf 3.7.1 generated sources with the protobuf 3.8.0+ jars (and vice versa).

In your example you generate the sources with protobuf 3.9.0 but ship protobuf 3.7.1 in your dependencies thus you get a conflict.

Comment: Yes, both build and generated code in src directory is working, my main question is is there anything wrong with plugin or ide for that warning to go.

Comment: Sorry I missuderstood your question. I updated my answer accordingly.